# Nginx rewrite redirect rule ignored for php files

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I'm moving my website to my new server so to keep things synced while the IP is updated in DNS records worldwide I wanna to put a temporary message on my old server to block any further activity.

My config

```
server {
    listen   80 default; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/nginx-default;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }


    location /mirror {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/mirror/moving.php redirect;

    }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }



    index index.php;
}
```

The site I wanna block is in /mirror and I want every request starting in that folder (files included) to be redirected to /mirror/moving.php. The current rule works for every request and file but not for .php files which are served normally, I suppose because they are passed to php5-fpm.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Same issue than in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937947/express-js-app-with-nginx-a-conflict-with-static-files-when-serving-a-subfolde/26952607).

Comment: Also, why use a php file for what should be a static notice. Last but not least, you want to rewrite to something outside that location if possible to avoid loops.